# Do a wire tap on all exchanges on a RabbitMQ server

Tags: rabbitmq, messaging, masstransit

I want to create a UI to see all the messages that are flowing through all exchanges in RabbitMQ server (of course other than the management console).

I am also using Mass Transit over rabbit but i am not sure if this matters.

Is this at all possible without having to code a consumer for each one of them one by one? If yes, any starting points?

Answer (score 2):

The message exchanges used for publishing, as well as sending, are all bound to an exchange that has the same name as the queue for message delivery. So you could bind your own wire tap exchange on the broker to any queue exchange, and wiretap the messages to another queue of your choosing.

You can view the RabbitMQ topology layout in the [documentation](http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/understand/default-topology.html).

It was specifically done this way to make it easy to wiretap any endpoint, since all messages flow through a single fanout exchange.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty broad question because it's not entirely obvious what you mean by "see", but regardless, you could create an observer on your bus. It's documented here and I think it's fairly straightforward: https://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/usage/observers.html

In the observer you can handle various events when *any* message hits the MT message bus, and perform some kind of operation (like print the message, add logging, metrics, etc). If you have a microservice scenario it might be a good idea to add an observer to your shared library and add it to the bus in your individual applications.